# Open Annotator (Where are comments stored?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, annotations

I need to figure out where Open Annotator stores its tags. The comments appear on mousehover over an annotation, but only one comment appears at a time in the html body. How can I get access to the array containing the comment information. [Here](https://github.com/openannotation/annotator) is the source to the project. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/frelacer/jUyC7/) is the JSFiddle.

Open Annotator Initializer:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#content').annotator()
             .annotator('addPlugin', 'Filter');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/) does not store annotations or highlights anywhere by default. They exist only in the state of the JavaScript code during that single page load **unless** you add a storage plugin of some kind.

There is a core [Store plugin](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/plugins/store.html) available that works with [AnnotateIt.org](http://annotateit.org/) by default, but can also work with any other implementation of the [Storage HTTP API](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/storage.html).

Lastly, there are a few plugins that offer other forms of storage. If you search the [Plugins list](http://annotatorjs.org/plugins/index.html) for `stor` you should find at least 3 (as of this writing).

Hope that helps!